# Cannot import 'Dimensions' attribute values in Magento through data flow import?

Tags: magento, csv, dataflow

I have created a custom attribute in Magento for my products and I import all products via the CSV data flow import.

One of my attributes 'dimensions' has values like '1020 x 1020 x 500-1900mm' which for some reason I cannot import. The CSV uploads successfully without generating any errors but the values for dimension don't show up for any of the products in the website.

I also tried just import the dimensions attribute with SKU to update but that didn't work as well?

But if I update the dimensions in the backend one by one for products, it works and shows up in the website and also in the exported CSV.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you indexing product attributes after you import?

Comment: Yes. 
If I export the CSV, it shows N/A for dimensions for all products.

Comment: I suggest using Magmi for importing instead, download it here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/ -- once you've dl'd it and filled in DB settings, just include `sku` in one column and your `dimensions` attribute in another, import it and it should work. Also see:http://www.blinkdata.com/magmi-documentation/ for any questions you may have about it.

Comment: Very good, just remember to re-index in *Configuration -> Index Management* after you import something.

Comment: Just tried the same using Magmi but got the same result. Import was successful but the dimensions don't show up.

Comment: Include more information then, list all attributes you selected when creating this attribute (take a screenshot maybe). Which attribute set did you assign this attribute to? I need more details to help.